# heavy or strong taste in doing things

Tags: meaning, synonyms, non-native-english

Is there a phrase or word to express "have a heavy/strong taste in doing things or about sex" can I use "hardcore" ijn this situation?

Comment: Please re-formulate this question. As it stands it does not make much sense. The word hardcore comes from porn movies, but is increasingly used to denote obsessive or intense behaviour in almost anything such as "He is a hardcore gamer". If you are looking for a word to describe sexual behaviour, hardcore does (no longer) work. Perhaps "perverse" or "sadistic" is where you need to look

Comment: Ok,then,forget "hadcoe". How can I express the meaning of "strong taste" in a more idiomatic way?

Comment: You should elaborate on what you mean by "strong taste." Give a couple examples. Take your time and be thoughtful about it. Also, edit your question, don't clarify down here in the comments.

Comment: Are you referring to 'things' or 'sex' or both - please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may need to reformulate this answer if you edit your question but you may be able to use the following:

[***Penchant***](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/penchant):

> a strong or habitual liking for something or tendency to do something:
>   or:

[***Proclivity***](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/proclivity):

> a tendency to choose or do something regularly; an inclination or predisposition towards a particular thing

For example: "Ralph has a penchant for whips and chains but Sue had a proclivity for candles and rose petals".

If you are talking about a woman you could use [***Nymphomania***](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/proclivity):

> uncontrollable or excessive sexual desire in a woman.

...or [Satyromania](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satyromania) in men.

Answer (score 0):

Does 'intense' work?            ? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an overarching and relatively informal term I suggest

[***fixated***](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/fixate?q=fixate)

> verb
>   [with object]
>   1 (usually be **fixated on/upon**) cause (someone) to acquire an obsessive attachment to someone or something: *she has for some time been fixated on photography*
>
> [no object] (fixate on/upon) acquire an obsessive attachment to:
>   *it is important not to fixate on animosity*